# java.sql.Timestamp implementation of Google Android API 10 2.3.3

Tags: java, android, timestamp, android-sdk-2.3

Code:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
Timestamp startTimestamp = new Timestamp(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
System.out.println("startTimestamp = " + startTimestamp);
System.out.println("startTimestamp.getYear() = " + startTimestamp.getYear());
```

Output:

```
startTimestamp = 3912-02-01 00:00:00.0
startTimestamp.getYear() = 2012
```

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) says:

**Parameters:**
year - the year minus 1900

So, 2012+1900=3912.

Comment: My date is 2012 and should we ok with the long timestamp, right?

Answer (score 0):

Note, that `new Timestamp(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);` is deprecated and I think is the root of your problem!

Use `Timestamp startTimestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());` instead.

Also, note that `startTimestamp.getYear()` is also deprecated!

> Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by
>   Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR).
>
> Returns the day of the month represented by this Date object. The
>   value returned is between 1 and 31 representing the day of the month
>   that contains or begins with the instant in time represented by this
>   Date object, as interpreted in the local time zone.

Consider this example (based on your original code):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    Timestamp startTimestamp = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
    System.out.println("startTimestamp = " + startTimestamp);
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2.setTimeInMillis(startTimestamp.getTime());
    System.out.println("Year = " + cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR));
}
```

It would produce output:

```
startTimestamp = 2012-01-01 12:00:00.0
Year = 2012
```